# Turn on relay for amount of time by continuous input

Tags: timers, relay, digital, input

I have a project having two input status

- first the input is not continuous the output buzzer relay will be on for 10 seconds and then turned off or it can be off directly by push button
- the second state if the input is continuous the output buzzer relay will be on for 10 seconds and then turned off or it can be off directly by push button

I made this code but it does not work can anyone suggest an edit without using millis() because it will crash after 49 days and without using delay function.

Note that the device will work 24 hours / 365 days.

```cpp
const int input1 = 19;
const int input2 = 36;
const int relay1 = 10;
const int relay2 = 21;
const int reset = 40;
const int buzzerreset = 45;
const int buzzerrelay = 46;

int buttonState1 = 0;    //for input1
int buttonState2 = 0;    //for input2
int buttonState3 = 0;    //for pushbutton
int buttonState4 = 0;    //for buzzer reset
int b4 = 0;              //for buzzer reset

void setup() {
  pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzerrelay, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(input1, INPUT);
  pinMode(input2, INPUT);
  pinMode(reset, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzerreset, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buzzerrelay, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState1 = digitalRead(input1);
  if (buttonState1 == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(buzzerrelay, HIGH);
    //delay(10000);
    //digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  }

  buttonState3 = digitalRead(reset);
  if (buttonState3 == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
    //digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  } else {
    buttonState4 = digitalRead(buzzerreset);

    if ((buttonState4 == HIGH || buttonState1 == HIGH) && b4 == LOW) {
      digitalWrite(buzzerrelay, LOW);
    }
    // while (digitalRead(input1) == HIGH);
    // digitalWrite(buzzerrelay, LOW);

    (buttonState2 = digitalRead(input2));
    if (buttonState2 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(buzzerrelay, HIGH);
      //delay(10000);
      //digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    }

    buttonState3 = digitalRead(reset);
    if (buttonState3 == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
      //digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    } else {
      buttonState4 = digitalRead(buzzerreset);
      if (buttonState4 == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(buzzerrelay, LOW);
      }
      //while (digitalRead(input2) == HIGH);
      //digitalWrite(buzzerrelay, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `millis` doesn't crash after 50 days. It just overflows, and starts back at zero. This is only a problem if you compare two timestamps. You can get around this problem all together by calculating the difference of the two timestamps. You can then check if the difference is more that 10000ms in you case. For example `if( millis()-buzzerStartTime > 10000){/*stop buzzer*/}`

Comment: Could you expand on the `it does not work ` part? What happens when you run your code? What do you expect do happen when you run your code?

Comment: why do you bother with states? ... your description says that the buzzer does the same thing in both states ... all you have to do, is to sound the buzzer for 10 seconds

Comment: when i run the code if the input not contentious there is no problem with the timer ,but when is the input is contentious the buzzer is also contentious and this is the problem i want the buzzer run for 10 seconds every time one of the inputs go HIGH (i have 25 inputs) even the input is contentious or not .  – Gerben

Comment: You say that when you detect an input (continuous or intermittent) you want to turn on a buzzer for 10 seconds, then turn it off again. What should it to once the buzzer is off again? Should it have a "lock-out" period where it ignores the input? Or should it simply wait for another input? Once 10 seconds has passed, should it wait until the input goes to the off sate before looking for a new trigger?

Comment: simply the buzzer will turned ON for 10 seconds in all cases( continuous or intermittent input )and wait for another trigger from another input if input is go high the buzzer will go ON for 10 seconds and so on @DuncanC

Comment: What if the input turns on and stays on for 5 minutes? How should the buzzer behave then?

Comment: the input could be go ON for a month the buzzer should be ON for 10 seconds and then turn of and ignore the input state until the input goes LOW

Comment: That's what I thought. You need to update your question to make that clear. My answer explains how to do that. Is there only one buzzer that buzzes if any of your inputs goes on, or does each input have its own buzzer?

Comment: yes there is one buzzer in the circuit

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a `buzzerPlaying` state, an `oldInput` state, and a `buzzerOffTime` (unsigned long millis when you should turn the buzzer off.

Ignore input if `buzzerPlaying == true` and just check the `buzzerOffTime`. When `buzzerOffTime` passes, turn off the buzzer, set `buzzerPlaying` to false, and start checking the input again.

If the `buzzerPlaying == false` and input is high:

1. check `buzzerPlaying`. If it's true, do nothing.
2. If `buzzerPlaying` is false, check `oldInput`. If `oldInput` is high, do nothing (The input has not been reset.) else set buzzerPlaying to true, set oldInput to high, turn on the buzzer, and calculate `buzzerOffTime`.

If the `buzzerPlaying == false` and input is low, set oldInput to low (Once the buzzer has stopped playing and the input has dropped low, start looking for more inputs.)

Comment: thanks for replay , im new to arduino and i have 25 inputs and 25 outputs i do not think that i could handle adding  this three status to my code put i will try hope it will work @

Comment: 25 inputs and 25 outputs? That means you need 50 i/o pins. Do you have an Arduino with that many pins?

Comment: i will use arduino mega 23 input and 23 output and pin for buzzer and pin for buzzer reset and pin for output reset that will be 49 i/o

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the inputs do, when one of them first goes HIGH you want the buzzer to sound, stopping after 10 seconds or a button-press, whichever comes first?
Then you need something like this:

```
if any input is HIGH,
   save millis();
   start the buzzer;

   if button is HIGH
      stop the buzzer;
   else if millis() - saved millis() >= 10*1000 millisec),
      stop the buzzer;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for replay i will try this

Comment: This pseudocode will have the buzzer play continuously as long as any input is high. The OP wants the buzzer to only play for 10 seconds, whether the input stays on or not. And they said they only want the buzzer to play again if the input goes low again once the buzzer stops. There need to be some state variables as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's right. :) And the psuedo-code reflects the problem statement as it had been stated until they clarified it in response to your pointing that out. That was 5 hours after my post.